Do bootloader and bootimage contain std features in newer versions?
I am trying to create a bare-metal OS in Rust and I am encountering numerous errors related to unfound types such as Vec and other standard library features. I suspect that these errors are due to dependencies relying on std, even though the only dependencies I have are bootimage and bootloader, which I assumed would not use std.
This is a part of the error
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `std`
  |
  = note: the `x86_64-ferrite_os` target may not support the standard library
  = note: `std` is required by `semver_parser` because it does not declare `#![no_std]`
  = help: consider building the standard library from source with `cargo build -Zbuild-std`


error: cannot find macro `try` in this scope
   --> /home/cosmin/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/semver-parser-0.7.0/src/range.rs:184:22
    |
184 |     let predicates = try!(predicates);
    |                      ^^^

error: cannot find macro `vec` in this scope
   --> /home/cosmin/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/semver-parser-0.7.0/src/range.rs:164:25
    |
164 |             predicates: vec![Predicate {
    |                         ^^^

the scope errors are continuing and there are a lot more
Here are the relevant parts of my Cargo.toml file:
[package]
name = "ferriteos"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
bootimage = "0.10.3"
bootloader = "0.11.7"

[build-dependencies]
bootimage = "0.10.3"

and .cargo/config.toml:
[unstable]
build-std = ["core", "compiler_builtins"]
build-std-features = ["compiler-builtins-mem"]

[build]
target = "resources/x86_64-ferrite_os.json"

The target specified looks like this and the only issue that I had with it was data layout problems but I fixed them:
{
    "llvm-target": "x86_64-unknown-none",
    "data-layout": "e-m:e-p270:32:32-p271:32:32-p272:64:64-i64:64-i128:128-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128",
    "arch": "x86_64",
    "target-endian": "little",
    "target-pointer-width": "64",
    "target-c-int-width": "32",
    "os": "none",
    "executables": true,
    "linker-flavor": "ld.lld",
    "linker": "rust-lld",
    "panic-strategy": "abort",
    "disable-redzone": true,
    "features": "-mmx,-sse,+soft-float"
}

The main.rs file includes !#[no_std] and i just try to print hello world to vga screen:
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

#[panic_handler]
fn panic(_info: &core::panic::PanicInfo) -> ! {
    loop {}
}

static HELLO: &[u8] = b"Hello World!";

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn _start() -> ! {
    let vga_buffer = 0xb8000 as *mut u8;

    for (i, &byte) in HELLO.iter().enumerate() {
        unsafe {
            *vga_buffer.offset(i as isize * 2) = byte;
            *vga_buffer.offset(i as isize * 2 + 1) = 0xb;
        }
    }

    loop {}
}

But I was wondering if the error is from dependencies and I need to try and downgrade and if anyone can help me with a stable version?
For any questions about reproducing this example. most of the code is taken from this tutorial
https://os.phil-opp.com/freestanding-rust-binary/
https://os.phil-opp.com/minimal-rust-kernel/

Indeed, both crates require std.
The bootimage crate was never meant to be used as a dependency; it is an installable (cargo install) tool.
The bootloader used to be used as a dependency in version 0.9, but saw significant changes since. There is a migration guide for users of v.0.9.
